# The type or namespace name 'HockeyApp' could not be found?

Tags: xamarin.android, hockeyapp

My Xamarin Hockey project for Android has some error as shown:

> CS0246    The type or namespace name 'HockeyApp' could not be found (are
> you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
> ...\Helpers\CrashListener.cs  9   Active
>
> CS0246  The type or namespace name 'SignaturePad' could not be found
> (are you missing a using directive or an assembly
> reference?)   ...Fragment.cs  12  Active

What means Hockey and SignaturePad?

I am new to Xamarin and Hockey platform.

Is there a way how do I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

HockeyApp is a service to distribute your apps and collect crash reports. If you didn't add the [HockeySDK NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/HockeySDK.Xamarin/) yourself, probably somebody else in your team did. You either need to restore NuGet packages or make sure that the HockeySDK NuGet was added to the project.